# byte indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python

I'm trying to run the below code

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
    
companies = requests.get(f'https://fmpcloud.io/api/v3/stock-screener? industry=Software&sector=tech&marketCapLowerThan=10000000000&limit=100&apikey=c609af2465eb19e3c82f0c3c38cb51ea')
companies.json()
```

At this point it's working fine but when getting to the following part , I was receiving an error

```
    technological_companies = []
    for item in companies:
        technological_companies.append(item['symbol'])
    print(technological_companies)
```

The error was :

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-61eef8b7699a> in <module>
1 technological_companies = []
2 for item in companies:
----> 3     technological_companies.append(item['symbol'])
4 print(technological_companies)

TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not storing the JSON value, use

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
    
companies = requests.get(f'https://fmpcloud.io/api/v3/stock-screener? industry=Software&sector=tech&marketCapLowerThan=10000000000&limit=100&apikey=c609af2465eb19e3c82f0c3c38cb51ea')
companies = companies.json() # this is the line
```

Answer (score 1):

Either store the json:

`companies = companies.json()`

Or loop over the json:

`for item in companies.json():`